# Imagemagick: how to compare two images and obtain a third image with the differences?

Tags: imagemagick

Anyone knows how to make imagemagick output an image with the differences between two other images? Similar to a diff, but not exactly the same. Any other Windows/Linux commandline tool that can be scripted would be good too (because I need to do this with hundreds of images).

Quick and dirty example:
Let's say I have these two images:

[image: Image A]
[image: Image B]

And I need to obtain only the curtain (and any other differences if there were), with everything else transparent.

Comment: Only Photoshop knowlwdge here. But if you have the difference PNG files with black already in one directory, you can create a PS action that walks through that directory, deletes the exact black and saves (as PNG). Possibly you need to change the background to be a layer before the deletion. Alternatively you can use a difference photo as it's own layer mask. Before saving you maybe want to make all non-black in the mask full white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the first example in the [ImageMagick documentation](http://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php):

```
magick compare -compose src du2SX.png ejUjy.png difference.png
magick difference.png -transparent "#CCCCCC" alpha.png
```

In "difference.png" the identical pixels are rendered in mid-gray:
[image]

The second command makes those pixels transparent:
[image]

Using `+transparent` instead of `-transparent` inverts things so you get:

[image]

Finally, use this as a mask

```
magick composite -compose copy_opacity alpha.png du2SX.png result.png
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I was doing already, but that's not exactly what I'm asking for. I don't want a red mark telling me where the differences are, but an output with the actual differences, the curtain (in that example) as a separate image.

Comment: That's what the commands give you.  Is the second (red on transparent) image not what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my primary language and I might have not explained it well. The output I want would be this:

http://i.imgur.com/XH8TiXX.png.

Comment: OK you want the original curtain, so you need to turn the red part into a mask and use that to extract the curtain from the original image.

Comment: Perfect, lots of thanks. Managed to do it by adding this command:
 
magick composite -compose copy_opacity alpha.png original.png result.png

Comment: I added your final composite comand to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Glenn's answer still mostly works six years later. You'll just need to make slight adjustments to the highlight and lowlight color.

> magick compare -highlight-color "#c00018" -lowlight-color "#CCCCCC"
> -compose src du2SX.png ejUjy.png difference.png

I found, that the default high- and lowlight color is slightly transparent and thus won't work with the -transparent argument in the next step.

(I would have made this into a comment, but my reputation is too low. I just made this account, so people won't run into the same trouble as me.)

Answer (score 0):

convert pic1.png ( -clone 0 pic2.jpg -compose difference -composite -threshold 5% -fill red -opaque white -transparent black ) -compose over -composite pic_compare.png

[ImageMagick - use compare operation to generate diff image](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29823)